# Check if the string contains an entire word from an array of words (jquery, javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on importing a word filter into a text input and I want to check if there is a match between a **entire** bad word that is in a array of words and a word that is inside a string, I will give an example of this...

List of bad words:

```
var bad_words = ['bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3'];
```

String with the value of text input:

```
var check_text = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

Lets say I have this word in my string (In this example I expect a **false** answer):

```
Here is bad2222
```

Lets say I have this word in my string (In this example I expect a **true** answer):

```
Here is bad2
```

Comment: Why don't you split by ```" "``` then loop through the resulting array?

Comment: `check_text.split(' ').some(part => bad_words.includes(part));`

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a “I need this, you make for me” kind of site. You are supposed to show at least an _attempt_ in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a slight correction to the code,

This is the code that solved this problem for me..Thx to ritaj

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function check_val() {
        var bad_words = ['bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3'];
        var check_text = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var error = 0;

        if (check_text.split(' ').some(part => bad_words.includes(part))) {
            error = error + 1;
        }

        if (error > 0) {
            document.getElementById("bad_notice").innerHTML = "WARNING: Some Bad Words In Your Text";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("bad_notice").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <textarea id="text" onKeyUp="check_val()" placeholder="Write Some Text Having Words 'bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3'"></textarea>
    <p id="bad_notice"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried your solution. Supposing I have an array of words _[bad1, bad2, bad3]_. This I want to check against a string of words (a sentence if you will) eg. **It is a bad1 lemon.** And the function is able to detect this correctly. However, if the _sentence_ has an extra **space** (say between _bad1 and lemon_, the check fails. Any thoughts on this? Thanks for a nice solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the reverse technique to check it.

```js
var bad_words = ['bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3'];
    const check_text = 'Here is bad222';
    
    const found = bad_words.find(word => check_text.split(' ').find(s=>s===word));
    if(found){
       console.log("True")
    }else{
       console.log("False")
    }
```